# Is it wrong to re-obfuscate obfuscated code?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I've used java obfuscators in the past and some are easy to reverse engineer.  I've thought maybe it wasn't obfuscated enough.

Is it wrong or problematic to apply two-stage obfuscation?

1. Obfuscate with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)
2. Finish it off with a commercial product [Zelix Klassmaster](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/)

--

Or is that a bad approach? Should only one obfuscator be used?

Comment: It's "okay" in the sense that nothing bad will happen.

Comment: I think that's a good question. Don't know why it got a "close" vote. Maybe should be rephrased a bit.

Comment: I voted to close because it's not clear what "okay" vs. "bad" mean, in an objective sense.

Comment: @oli, you could have asked Kyle to rephrase it instead of voting to close.

Comment: @oli, I've reworded my question.

Comment: @Oli, I googled about this and it got me to this site, so what's the problem? You people need to get off your high horse; this site isn't just for professional developers. If you want to make it that way though(which a lot of you are) I'm sure I can find another site where I feel more welcome. I guarantee I'm not the only one who is walking that line.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the code still runs correctly, then no matter what numbers of obfuscator you use, it should be OK. Remember that the main concern of using obfuscator is to make the code unreadable as far as possible while maintaining its correctness.

Answer (score 2):

re-obfuscating obfuscated code is a well know method of unobfuscating code.
e.g. you can obfuscate classes to have names that do not form valid windows file names like

```
class COM1 { ... }
```

decompiling that would result in a file named COM1.java, which is not a valid windows filename and thus breaks many decompilers.

The solution would be to first re-obfuscate using a dictionary of names like class1, class2, method1, method2, field1, field2 and then decompile. The decompiled code will now not only be more valid to decompile, but more readable too.

Using obfuscators in serial would usually result in obfuscated code as strong as the last obfuscator used. (i.e. the chain is as strong as the last link)

I suggest you stick to one obfuscator but make sure you understand each and every option in the obfuscation process and how easy it is to undo.

Comment: Imagine the last obfuscater simply copied the code. How can that make previous obfuscation steps less effective? I think it is as strong as the strongest link.

Comment: @IraBaxter I understand what you mean, yet a lot of obfuscation techniques can be undone by re-obfuscating.

Comment: 'Using obfuscators in serial would usually result in obfuscated code as strong as the last obfuscator used. (i.e. the chain is as strong as the last link)' Why?

Comment: Some obfuscators obfuscate by adding unnecessary and misleading code. Other obfuscators remove unnecessary code (not as part of the obfuscation, but as part of optimizing). Clearly putting those 2 in serial will not create a stronger chain.
Similarly, obfuscating by making the class names invalid windows filenames, then obfuscating by making the classnames as small as possible will also undo what has been done.

Comment: If an obfuscator's result ("add unnecessary code") is trivially removable by mechanical methods ("simple dead code analysis"), then that obfuscator isn't very strong.  So agreed that two in a row doesn't make it stronger. But that isn't my point.  Re your example, one that scrambles file names isn't reversible by mechanical means, even if you apply another one that achieves the same effect a different way.